# Displaying status circles

Tags: website-design, color, shapes

I am currently working on webproject and responsible for the design. I have a list , where I shall display the trackingstatus of each list-item. For each step I have 4 possible outcomes. I wanted to use the main colors, we have defined in our applicaiton. My current situation looks like this:

[image]

For me it's just too much colors, yet I need to display the informations with using them.

Any alternative solution, you guys can think of? Or how do I accomplish to make the colors look not too childish?

Comment: Apart from the fact that the two greens are *very* similar, I don't see any problem with those colors.

Answer (score 1):

Marking the status of a list-item is definetly best with using simplest possible solutions, colors are the best in my opinion for that.

As for the **alternatives** you can always go for some icons related to the current state of the particular item. There are many ready-to-use icons such as [Flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/) or [Freepik](http://www.freepik.com/free-vectors/icons) and many more if you use your search-engine extensively.

However, I would definetly go for the color option. As it will be the easiest to comprehend for the user.

Comment: Well we use font-awesome. However they have not that many logistics-icons.